# Make image the same height as the rest of the the table row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which contains several columns of text, plus one with an image (icon).

I want the icon to be scaled to fit in with the height of the row, even when the table is resized.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642539/shrink-image-size-to-fit-table-cell-which-works-in-all-browsers) looked like it would help, but it did not.

Of course, I am looking for a cross browser solution, but am willing to limit it to "modern" browsers.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td><img src="http://localhost/images/small_gold_star.png"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code ?

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: absolute positioning could help, but table could also overflow since last col would have no width :( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKzrpQ

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the image as a background of your `td`. Then set the `background-size` property of that image to `cover` or `contain`. The `cover` value will:

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area

The `contain` value will:

> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its
>   height can fit inside the content area

Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some text here</td>
      <td>Some more text here</td>
      <td>More and more and more and more and more text here</td>
      <td class="icon"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<style>
  td.icon {
    background: url(my-icon.png);
    background-size: cover; /*MAYBE "contain"?*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I can't figure out why it isn't working for me in Chrome